# How do I get rid of sand spurs?

Tags: lawn, weed-control

How do I get rid of sand spurs?

These suckers pop up all over my lawn around this time of year, and I'm not sure how to get rid of them other than constantly pulling them out. Obviously I can't use a broad-leaf herbicide or anything like that. What can I do?

[image]

Comment: Common Sawgrass or Sedge. Too Wet by far if you have this growing.

Comment: Well, it has been raining a lot, but I haven't been watering the yard at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the seedhead of a sedge. You can control them with [Dismiss,](http://www.fmcprosolutions.com/Portals/pest/Content/Docs/Labels/Dismiss%20CA%20Turf%20Herbicide%2011-01-12R%20Comm.pdf) a post-emergent selective herbicide with the active ingredient [sulfentrazone,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfentrazone) which is compatible with the following lawn grasses:

- Zoisiagrass
- Perennial Ryegrass
- Tall Fescue
- Centipedegrass
- Kentucky Bluegrass
- Bermudagrass,
- Creeping Bentgrass
- Bahia Grass

Or you can use [Basagran T/O,](http://betterturf.basf.us/products/basagran-t-o-herbicide.html) another good post-emergent, that has the active ingredient [bentazon.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentazon) This is compatible with the following grasses:

- Zoisiagrass
- Perennial Ryegrass
- Tall Fescue
- Centipedegrass
- Kentucky Bluegrass
- Bermudagrass,
- Creeping Bentgrass
- St. Augustinegrass
- Bahia Grass

Use as directed on the product label. I would suggest not using these if you are near a body of water, to avoid contamination.

You can also use a [glufosinate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glufosinate) based herbicide, to spot shoot plants in your lawn. This may leave a dead spots in you lawn, but will use much less chemicals.

Comment: Many sedges make marvellous plants for the waters edge.  The ones in the picture are just in the wrong place.

Comment: @kevinsky I agree, and you shouldn't really use herbicides near water anyway.

Comment: And don't overwater...

Comment: @kevinsky, are you saying this plant is useful somehow?

Comment: @user4630 some wet-foot tolerant sedges are used as ornamental plants for pond edges, or marshes. They are tough, and some species are fairly attractive.

Comment: @user4630 yes, jmusser and I both know sedges as ornamental plants.  They are just not in the right place for you.